# Ontario HST rebate: How does it work for a single parent with joint custody?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

I'm a single father with joint custody of my son... Just wondering what rebate I will get? ... the $100 or $300...?

Answer (score 1):

The [Ontario Ministry of Revenue](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca) has posted a Frequently Asked Question about your situation:

[I am single and my ex-spouse and I share custody of our child. Will I receive the OSTTB payment at the family rate or the single rate?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_calculation.html#Q21).  Quote:

> The parent who is the primary
>   caregiver of a child on the specified
>   date will receive the OSTTB payment at
>   the family rate. The parent who is the
>   primary caregiver on May 31, 2010 will
>   receive the June 10, 2010 payment at
>   the family rate, the parent who is the
>   primary caregiver on November 30, 2010
>   will receive the December 2010 payment
>   at the family rate, and the parent who
>   is the primary caregiver on May 31,
>   2011 will receive the June 2011
>   payment at the family rate.
>
> The parent who is not the primary
>   caregiver at the time will receive an
>   OSTTB payment at the single rate.

And a related FAQ:  [How will the CRA determine which parent is the primary caregiver?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_administration.html#Q22)  Quote:

> The first determining factor is which
>   parent receives the federal Canada
>   Child Tax Benefit (CCTB) for the month
>   in which the applicable OSTTB payment
>   will be made. If the child is not
>   registered for the CCTB, or neither
>   parent is eligible for the CCTB, then
>   the determining factor is which
>   claimed the federal Child Tax Credit
>   amount for the child on the previous
>   year's income tax return.